# Selecting Data from 3 tables in Oracle Apex

Tags: mysql, oracle, select, join

I have four tables called: **dw_location, dw_time, dw_crime and dw_crime_fact**.

**dw_location** contains the columns **area_id** and **area_name**.

**dw_time** contains the columns time_id and year.
**dw_crime** contains the columns **crime_type_id** and **crime_type_desc**.

**dw_crime_fact** contains the columns **report_id**, no_of **crimes**, **fk1_time_id** as a **foreign key from dw_time**, **fk2_area_id** as a **foreign key dw_location** and **fk3_crime_type_id** as a **foreign key from dw_crime**.

One of the reports I want to produce is the area with the highest crime per year.

I have got the following code for the joining of the tables and I am struggling to select the area and year with the highest number of crimes. 
Im pretty sure I have to use the `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` statements but not sure where to put them .

```
SELECT dw_time.year, dw_location.area_desc, 
FROM dw_crime_fact
INNER JOIN dw_time ON dw_time.time_id=dw_crime_fact.fk1_time_id
INNER JOIN dw_location ON dw_location.area_id=dw_crime_fact.fk2_area_id
AND FK1_TIME_ID = '1'
```

The above code brings up a list of areas in the year 2009. But I want to select the area with the highest amount of crime.

Answer (score 0):

You would need more details on what to do when there are ties for the highest crime, etc. but hopefully something like this gets you on the right track:

```
with data as (
    select 2009 year, 'A' area_desc, 3 no_of_crimes from dual union all
    select 2009 year, 'A' area_desc, 2 no_of_crimes from dual union all
    select 2009 year, 'B' area_desc, 1 no_of_crimes from dual union all
    select 2009 year, 'C' area_desc, 7 no_of_crimes from dual union all
    select 2009 year, 'D' area_desc, 3 no_of_crimes from dual union all
    select 2009 year, 'D' area_desc, 5 no_of_crimes from dual union all
    select 2009 year, 'E' area_desc, 6 no_of_crimes from dual
)
select year, area_desc, tot_crimes
from (
    select
           year,
           area_desc,
           sum(no_of_crimes) tot_crimes,
           rank() over (partition by year order by sum(no_of_crimes) desc) rnk  
    from data
    group by year, area_desc
)
where rnk = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if this is what you're looking for.

```
SELECT dw_time.year, dw_location.area_desc, no_of crimes
FROM dw_crime_fact
INNER JOIN dw_time ON dw_time.time_id=dw_crime_fact.fk1_time_id
INNER JOIN dw_location ON dw_location.area_id=dw_crime_fact.fk2_area_id
AND FK1_TIME_ID = '1'
order by dw_crime_fact.no_of_crimes desc
limit 1
```